# Search through a list of items to find a specific item with content in a specific attribute

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items. In each LI is a custom attribute called `data-index`.

I want to search through the items and find each item where a specific string is present in the attribute.

I'm including the whole thing here. Any suggestions? Am I headed in the right direction?

My expectation is if I search for bg19 I'll only get one report in the console.log. I'm getting 10 each time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>A selectable list</title>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <style>
        .hidden {

            display:none;
        }

        .show {

            display:block;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#id-submit').on('click', $(this), function() {
                var userId = $('#user-id').val();
                $('#user-app-list').children('li').attr('data-index', userId).each(function() {
                    console.log('Here we go');
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>To select your library, enter your ID number and click submit.</h3>
    <form>
        <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter ID Here" id="user-id">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="id-submit">
    </form>
    <ul id="user-app-list">
        <li data-index="cd123 cd124 cd125 bg12 bg19 bg20" class="hidden">
            <h3><a href="http://apple.com">Apple</a></h3>
        </li>
        <li data-index="cd127 cd128 cd130 bg12" class="hidden">
            <h3><a href="http://amazon.com">Amazon</a></h3>
        </li>
        <li data-index="cd121 cd119 cd125 bg12" class="hidden">
            <h3><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></h3>
        </li>
        <li data-index="cd123 cd124 cd125 bg12 bg20" class="hidden">
            <h3><a href="http://youtube.com">YouTube</a></h3>
        </li>
        <li data-index="cd123 cd124 cd125 bg12 bg20" class="hidden">
            <h3><a href="http://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a></h3>
        </li>
        <li data-index="cd127 cd127 cd120 bg12 bg20" class="hidden">
            <h3><a href="http://ebay.com">Ebay</a></h3>
        </li>
        <li data-index="cd127 cd119 cd118 bg12 bg20" class="hidden">
            <h3><a href="http://craigslist.org">Craigslist</a></h3>
        </li>
        <li data-index="cd128 cd127 cd130 bg12 bg20" class="hidden">
            <h3><a href="http://inside.com">Inside</a></h3>
        </li>
        <li data-index="cd129 cd119" class="hidden">
            <h3><a href="http://cnn.com">CNN</a></h3>
        </li>
        <li data-index="cd130 cd118 cd125 bg12 bg20" class="hidden">
            <h3><a href="http://bbc.com">BBC</a></h3>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <p>Test with any of the following: cd118, cd119, cd120, cd121, cd123, cd124, cd125, cd127, cd128, cd129, cd130, bg12, bg19, bg20</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an [attribute contains word selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/) like `$('#user-app-list').children('li[data-index~="'+userId+'"]')`.

[Attribute Contains Word Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   containing a given word, delimited by spaces.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id-submit').on('click', $(this), function () {
        var userId = $('#user-id').val();
        $('#user-app-list').children('li').hide().filter('[data-index~="' + userId + '"]').show();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sBJX3/)

What you are doing is to set the value of the `data-index` attribute

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PjLzH/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var userId = $('#user-id').val();
        $("#user-app-list li[data-index~='" + userId + "']").each(function(event) {
            console.log('Here we go');
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```